# recalculate keyframe position after moving an animation

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes

is there an option to move and scale an animated group of objects?
for example i have a group of three animated objects. i want to move all that animation across the screen till it fits my needs without harm the animation and the relations between the animated objects.I can for instance delete all the y positions' to be able to move it on the y axis, but i can't find a way to scale it or to move in another directions without harming the entire animation.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi solution is very easy - add empty *"Shift+A"* -> "Empty" - choose one. And make this empty as parent of this objects: select all objects (with shift) and as last select empty (empty must be active object). Press "CTRL+P" -> "Object (Keep transform)". Now you ca move/scale empty and all object will follow it. Works also for animation.

Comment: Thnx very much!